# How to get browser link working in asp mvc 6 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser-link

I have created an empty asp mvc 6 project and added a index.html and a styles.css file. If i make changes to the stylesheet the browser does not get the newly created style, only if I reload the page does it work. If i press `ctrl` to get the browserlink options nothing happens there is no toolbar in the bottom left hand corner.

I am using IIS Express with the browserlink option enabled use `ctrl f5` run without debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to press the refresh button in Visual Studio to reload the page. Browser Link simply tells each of your selected browsers to refresh. It doesn't make it happen automatically while you make changes.

Also, you need to be debugging. Browser Link works in debugging, not simply by running the application.

See the guide at http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link for more information.

**Update**

Looks like you'll need to edit your app's `config.json` file (takes the place of `web.config` in ASP 5):

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "vs:EnableBrowserLink": "true"
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

If you're using an `appsettings.json` file, you don't need the `AppSettings` wrapper object:

```
{
    "vs:EnableBrowserLink": "true"
}
```

For more information, see the official documentation for configuration in ASP 5 at http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Comment: I am not getting any current connections from browserlink, even when i am running in debug mode. I never needed to run in debug mode with asp 4.5 . The thing is , asp 5 mvc6 does not have a web.config file. Should i maybe just try to get browser-sync to work instead through gulp?

Comment: My mistake, you'll need to add config.json in the place of web.config. I'm looking into whether this actually works with Browser Link.

Comment: I hope i can still use is. Its a was a lot easier to setup then browser-sync ,which is also not working, even if i run it through a node server

Comment: Updated - try this :)

Comment: Thank you! May i ask how you came to the solution?

Comment: Welcome! I found the guide linked in my answer on Google, and then looked up how to define AppSettings with the new config.json file :)

Comment: cant get this to work, seems like config.json is now appsettings.json and located in the project root (not where web.config was located). Anyone got this working with RC1?

Comment: @zedd if you're using appsettings.json, you can omit the "AppSettings" object wrapping the setting. Your entire appsettings.json could simply be: `{"vs:EnableBrowserLink": "true"}`